# JdbcTemplate do not mapping result to map : related with windows ascii

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ascii, special-characters, jdbctemplate

I got a dump file from `MSSQL`. It is encoded with `euckr` and has some windows ascii character like `^F`, `^D`, `M`.

What I am trying to do is ...

- `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{My CSV FILE}' INTO TABLE '{TARGET TABLE}' CHARACTER SET euckr FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|:'` - push csv to MYSQL
- read the data from MYSQL with `jdbcTemplate` on java source code

After `LOAD ...`, I can see the data in workbench and it looks normal.(It does not display any special characters I mentioned above.)

However, when execute `jdbcTemplate.queryForMap`, it could not push the result to `Map` and I assume MS ascii is the reason.

Error message is (I typed this since windows console does not able to copy)

```
org.springframwwork.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: 
PreparedStatedmentCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM TARGET_TABLE]; 
Value '^A4 data1    1999-00-00^Fabc^D0000^A0^@...'
```

How can I eliminate this special characters?

- Do I request new MSSQL dump file without those? (I do not know is it possible to eliminate in MSSQL. I have no experience with MSSQL)
- Is there anyway to do some works before jdbctemplate mapping result?

Thanks.

FYI,
Mysql encoding is `UTF8`, and version is `5.6.35`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but in my experiment ,,,

- `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` in Windows makes some weird characters like that.
- Execute same query in OSX or Linux(In my case, CentOS mysql client) looks fine.(Do not insert characters like `^M`)